# Sharing code between iOS apps and their watch apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchos-2

I have been trying to figure out the best way to structure my watch apps for the last couple of days, and haven't had a lot of success. Currently in my iPhone apps I have several libraries that I use for various standard things. This includes things like the base class of my data objects, helpers for converting them from JSON, and base classes for my services.

The problem that this causes for me is that I am unable to find a way to include these libraries in my watch extension, and this means that I can't even share any of the data objects from my main application because all of them rely on the library.

So, my question is, is there a way that I can share a library between my main app, and the watch app?

Comment: How are you currently trying to include them? Are you including the files in the Utilities panel under Target Membership?

Comment: I have tried sharing the libraries by including them in the Target Dependencies and the "Link Binaries with Libraries" area. Files that are not in my libraries I can include simply by adding the watch extension target, but that doesn't work if they reference one of the objects from one of my libraries... and just about everything does.

Comment: Yep, that's just how it works. You are going to need to include all the libraries and their dependencies. It really sucks unless you build it with this problem in mind from day one.

Comment: Well, I get that I need to have all of the dependencies included. The problem is that if I actually attempt to include a library with the watch extension it doesn't work. I can't figure out a way to build it so that it functions correctly for both the iOS app and the watch extension at the same time.

Comment: You are likely going to need to create duplicates for `watchOS`. If you go under each library's `Build Settings` they likely are `iOS` under `Supported Platforms`. You should change that to `watchOS` for the duplicate libraries.

Comment: Yeah... I noticed that that was an option. I was hoping that there was a better solution though. I guess that also means that all code that is going to be shared will have to be pulled into a library, because otherwise they will end up having linking issues due to attempting to use two separate libraries. That kinda sucks.

Thanks for the help though.